# Блокировки данных в InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы: пользователи (user) и телефоны (phone). При добавлении нового пользователя (ввод номера телефона) проверяется, нет ли такого номера в БД phone:

```
SELECT COUNT(phone.id) FROM phone WHERE phone.number = '1234567';
```

Если номера телефона нет в БД, тогда выполняется вставка данных:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM user

$newId = $maxId + 1;

INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES ('.$newId.', "Test")
INSERT INTO phone (id, user_id, number) VALUES (DEFAULT, '.$newId.' "1234567")
```

Подскажите, как правильно расставить блокировки на данные, чтобы не блокировать все таблицы (user и phone) для регистрации нового пользователя?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сочетать не сочетаемое. `insert_id` используется для автоинкрементных id, которые не задают руками и тем более не получают как `max(id)+1`. Использование `max(id)+1` вообще потребует полной блокировки таблицы. Нормальной практикой является: Выполняете insert в первую таблицу у которой поле id auto_increment (сам id в операции не указываете). После чего в `mysqi->insert_id` у вас содержится id только что вставленной записи, используете его для вставки записи во вторую таблицу.

Comment: @Mike Кто вам сказал такую чушь, про то, что id нельзя задавать вручную? Все зависит от задачи. В простых случаях, когда необходимо записать только 1 строку, безусловно, проще и лучше вставить автоинкрементный id как DEFAULT и получить id при помощи mysqi->insert_id.Если нужно вставить, например, за раз по 10, 100, 1000 записей в таблицу, то выполнять 10, 100, 1000 insert`ов вместо одного, чтобы получить id для каждой стоки - не рационально и глупо. И именно в таких ситуациях нужно получить max id, прибавить к нему единицу и сформировать все ID в скрипте, не используя автоинкремент БД.

Comment: @Mike По поводу блокировки всей таблицы, скорее всего тоже не верно, так как можно взять max id, прибавить к нему единицу и заблокировать в транзакции диапазон от (max_id + 1) и выше - так называемая блокировка в транзакции next-ket lock: SELECT * FROM t WHERE id > (maxId + 1). Поскольку ранее я не сталкивался с такими видами блокировок я и задал свой вопрос, в надежде, что те кто работал с такими видами блокировок помогут мне с составлением транзакции.

Comment: @Mike Для блокировки next-key lock все также нужно сначала получить max id, так что ваш комментарий про "сочетать не сочетаемое" и "тем более не получают как max(id)+1" я опроверг уже вторым аргументом.

Comment: Ложное утверждение: "И про сочетаемость: auto_increment на колонки ничего не знает о тех значениях что вы вставляете в таблицу самостоятельно, он свой счетчик не изменит после вставки и первая же вставка без id свалится по нарушению ключа, так как автоинкремент даст тот id, что вы вставили". Возьмите и сами проверьте.
А если в БД будут идти запросы как с заранее определенным ID, так и с DEFAULT? Тогда может все же autiincrement будет полезен? :)
Естественно, mysqli->insert_id не получит данные ни с SELECT, ни с INSERT с заранее установленным ID - зачем вы придумали, что я утверждал обратное?

Comment: Вместо использования давно устаревших версий программного обеспечения, может стоит отказаться от такого проекта или перевести его на более новую БД? У меня уже лет 5 запросы вставки используют DEFAULT и заранее установленные id для одной таблицы и ни разу не возникало проблем с  "нарушением ключа".

Comment: Будь моя воля я бы его давно уже на Postgresql перевел. проблем на порядок меньше было бы

Answer (score 1):

И так, наша задача заблокировать в таблице телефонов такую запись, что бы никто не мог в это время произвести вставку с таким же номером телефона. Если запись с таким номером уже есть, то все просто, достаточно было бы заблокировать ее. Но если записи нет, то блокировать нечего. Предлагаю в таком случае блокировать последнюю запись в таблице телефонов. Да, это приведет к блокировке всех, кто пытается добавить пользователя, но другого нормального пути нет. Запрос выполняющий это будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT phone FROM phone
 WHERE number = '1234567'
    OR id=(select max(id) from phone)
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 1
 FOR UPDATE
```

После запроса проверяем номер телефона, который он вернул. Если он совпадает с искомым, значит он уже есть и вставку делать не надо. Если не совпадает - значит получена (и заблокирована) последняя запись из таблицы, можно вставлять новые данные.

Обращаю ваше внимание, что использование `select max(id)+1` для поиска id для новой записи потребует полной блокировки всей таблицы. Следует пользоваться auto_increment id. Вообще не указывая поле id в операции insert. *После* выполненной вставки вам будет доступна mysqli->insert_id, с только что вставленным значением. И в дальнейших операциях надо использовать его.

Так же обращаю ваше внимание, что фраза `FOR UPDATE` в SQL запросе, производит блокировку, только если явно находитесь в транзакции. По этой причине убедитесь, что на соединении не включен режим [auto commit](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.autocommit.php). Блокировка на записи будет удерживаться вплоть до явного выполнения commit или rollback. Так что использовать их так же необходимо.

Comment: За этот ответ спасибо, но только неужели запрос `select max(id)` (+1 добавится в скрипте) в транзакции заблокирует всю таблицу на чтение? Мне нужно заблокировать только все, что выше max(id), начиная с max(id) + 1. Касательно того, почему использования mysqli->insert_id не всегда является лучшим вариантом я написал в комментариях выше.

Comment: @Miron `select max(id)` сама ничего не заблокирует. я имел ввиду, что нам надо самим брать полный лок. Но ввиду того, что пишут про next-key lock его то же вполне можно использовать, заменив в моем запросе `id=(...)` на `id>=(...)`. Результат запроса в общем то от этого не изменится, мы получим защиту от вставки следующей записи по id. Но к сожалению это не по номеру телефона.

Comment: Тогда, возможно, стоит применить такой запрос: SELECT user.*, phone.* FROM user LEFT JOIN  phone ON phone.id = (phone.maxId) WHERE user.id = (user.maxId) FOR UPDATE. В качестве значения maxId использовать максимально-допустимое значение для выбранного типа, например для INT UNSIGNED оно будет равно 4294967295. При использовании оператора "=" сработает gap lock, который заблокирует на запись диапазон от макс. существующего id в таблицах до 4294967295?

Comment: Назвали "извращением" - тогда может и потрудитесь объяснить свое мнение? Как по мне такой вариант единственно правильный, так как если пройдет запрос INSERT с другого соединения сразу после `SELECT max(id) FROM user` и перед `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id > (maxId + 1) FOR UPDATE` то заблокировано будет совсем не то, что нужно.

Comment: `id = (select max(id) from phone) ... FOR UPDATE` заблокирует последнюю запись, а не диапазон выше max(id) и разве FOR UPDATE не должно быть в круглых скобках? А если закончатся id из INT диапазона, т.е. будет более 4 294 967 295 (4-ех миллиардов!) пользователей, изменение int на bigint - это ничто по сравнению с другими проблемами, такими как увеличение производительности, кластеры и т.д, так что это мловероятная проблема.

Comment: @Miron нет, for update не должен быть в скобках. И я же в комментариях предлагал написать `>= (select max(id) ...)` что бы он взял next-key lock. А с окончанием id я уже сталкивался, поэтому думаю об этом заранее

Answer (score 0):

Добиться уникальности очень просто, и безо всяких блокировок. Достаточно просто сформулировать свою проблему. Поскольку само слово "уникальность" как бы намекает.

Достаточно добавить уникальный индекс на номер телефона. 
И, разумеется, вычистить весь тот ужас, который используется сейчас. Проблема решена.

Сначала надо сделать вставку в таблицу телефонов и обработать ошибку. В mysqli можно использовать ключевое слово ignore.
Если запись не вставилась - значит телефон уже есть, и никто никуда не идёт.
Если запись вставилась - **только после этого** создаем юзера, получаем **человеческим способом** user_id и обновляем строку с телефоном.
Для надежности можно все эти манипуляции завернуть в тарнзакцию.

Comment: Не стоит править вопрос, не вникнув в его содержание. Я не спрашивал как обеспечить уникальность, мне необходимо обеспечить консистентность данных при возможной одновременной вставке данных в две таблицы. Уникальный индекс по номеру телефона присутствует. Но проблема может возникнуть при проверке на уникальность, которую нужно выполнить до вставки данных, чтобы сообщить пользователю об ошибке, в случае дублирования номера. Также, на момент записи номера в таблицу необходимо иметь user id. В вашем варианте вместо одного insert придется каждый раз использовать insert + update, что не есть хорошо

Comment: Вот как раз про то, как организовать транзакцию с блокировками я и спрашивал в своем вопросе.